# How to get the new value of a qtreewidgetitem after entering new value

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I have created a treewidget and I have added some treewidgetitems which is editable.

My goal is now to catch the new value of the item after entering it.

Here is the code:

```
    QTreeWidgetItem* child = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    child->setText(0, "New Folder");
    child->setText(1, "--");
    child->setText(2, "--");
    child->setFlags(child->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
    item[0]->addChild(child);
    item[0]->setExpanded(true);
    MyTree->editItem(child);

    MyTree->setCurrentItem(child);
    ...
```

When "editItem" is set, I can on the interface enter manuel the new value. What I need is to be able the catch the new value after I press "enter" key. When the item become editable the name is "New Folder", the text is selected and I enter a new name such as "blabla" and press enter.

I need to catch the "blabla". I have tried using the code below:

```
    ....
    MyTree->setCurrentItem(child);

    QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> item;

    item = MyTree->selectedItems();
    QString str = item[0]->text(0);
    QByteArray latin_str = str.toLatin1();
    char *utf8_text = latin_str.data();
```

but the utf8_text report "New Folder" instead of "blabla"

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class derived from `QObject`, and listen to the `QTreeWidget`'s `itemChanged` signal. For example:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT;
public:
    MyWidget(QWidget * parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent)
    {
        // Create sub-widgets, including m_tree

        // Connect up signal and slot
        connect(&m_tree, SIGNAL(itemChanged(QTreeWidgetItem*, int)), this, SLOT(treeItemChanged(QTreeWidgetItem*, int)));
    }

public slots:
    void treeItemChanged(QTreeWidgetItem * item, int column);
    // ...

private:
    QTreeWidget m_tree;
};
```

N.B.: I haven't tested the code above, it's just an example. There are plenty of tutorials around on the use of Qt signals and slots.

Answer (score 0):

Use `QTreeWidget::itemChanged` signal and signal/slot. Small working example:

```
QObject::connect(MyTree,&QTreeWidget::itemChanged,[=](QTreeWidgetItem * item,int column) {
    qDebug() << item->text(column);
});
```

I used here `C++11` (`CONFIG += c++11` to `.pro` file) and [new syntax of signals and slots](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax), but of course you can use old syntax if you want.